# Need Accordion to Be Closed By Default on WordPress Site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, accordion

I am working on [this website](http://www.SoVeryInteractive.com) and there are 3 accordions that provide a list of services. I can't figure out how to make the accordion closed by default.

Additionally, there's a lot of extra space blank space between some of the accordion tabs and I can't figure out why that is.

This is in the "head" file:

```
<style>
.text-color, a.link-big:hover, .navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle, .portfolio-image:after, .blog-post h3 a:hover, footer .tweet_list .tweet_text a , .nav-pills > li > a:hover, .accordion-heading a, .home-header .link:hover 
 { color: #a9cc54; }
```

This is in the body:

```
<div class="wpb_accordion wpb_content_element  not-column-inherit" data-collapsible=yes>
    <div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_accordion_wrapper ui-accordion"> 
        <div class="wpb_accordion_section group">
            <h3 class="wpb_accordion_header ui-accordion-header"><a href="#">Content Creation &amp; Posting</a></h3>
            <div class="wpb_accordion_content ui-accordion-content clearfix">
                <div class=" align-left" style="color:;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Facebook</li>
                        <li>Twitter</li>
                        <li>Instagram</li>
                        <li>FourSquare</li>
                        <li>Pinterest</li>
                        <li>LinkedIn &amp; More&#8230;</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this on `js_composer_front.js`:

```
if ( typeof window['vc_accordionBehaviour'] !== 'function' ) {
    function vc_accordionBehaviour() {
        jQuery('.wpb_accordion').each(function(index) {
            var $tabs,
                interval = jQuery(this).attr("data-interval");
            //
            $tabs = jQuery(this).find('.wpb_accordion_wrapper').accordion({
                header: "> div > h3",
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: jQuery(this).data('collapsible') === 'yes',
                change: function(event, ui){
                    if(jQuery.fn.isotope!=undefined) {
                        ui.newContent.find('.isotope').isotope("reLayout");
                    }
                    vc_carouselBehaviour();
                }
            });
            //.tabs().tabs('rotate', interval*1000, true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make all Accordions inactive, we change the [**`active`** option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) to `false`:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'minimize_accordion_so_23758086' );

function minimize_accordion_so_23758086()
{
    # Not home or front page, bail out
    if( !is_home() || !is_front_page() )
        return;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
    {
        $('.wpb_accordion').each( function(index) 
        {
            $(this).find('.wpb_accordion_wrapper').accordion( "option", "active", false );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

<sup>See [*Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)</sup>

To fix the spacing issue, follow the hints from [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) or Firebug add-on for Firefox

[image: Chrome inspector]